# Flutter Routing Issue and Duplicate GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I'm having an issue with Flutter routes and a duplicate GlobalKey in the widget tree.

My app does the following:

```
Screen_A -> Screen_B -> Screen_C
```

In each case, the navigation (->) is done via the following (where * is B or C):

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen_*()));
```

I then navigate from `Screen_C -> Screen_A` via:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, 
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen_A()), 
    (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Finally, I navigate from `Screen_A -> Screen_B` using the original `Navigator.push` method. I'm getting the following error:

**'package:flutter/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 135 pos 12: 'route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true.**

**Exception caught by widgets library: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.**

For reference, `Screen_B` is a form wherein I define a GlobalKey via:

```
GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

I can't figure out why this is occurring. It appears where I define the GlobalKey and how I route is the proper way. Shouldn't `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` remove the route stack history, thereby removing the old GlobalKey in `Screen_B`?

Comment: If you are navigating from C to A at the end, why you don't use `pushReplacement()`  instead of `push()` to navigate from A to B and from B to C

Comment: Does pushReplacement() reset the navigation stack?

Comment: It deletes the screen from the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: The solution turned out to to be *where* I was putting the GlobalKey declaration. I previously had it outside of my stateful widget like so:

```
GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
class Screen_B extends StatefulWidget { (etc.) }
class _Screen_B extends State<Screen_B > { (etc.) }
```

But upon moving it *into* the State<Screen_B>, my issue was solved. Like so:

```
class Screen_B extends StatefulWidget { (etc.) }
class _Screen_B extends State<Screen_B > { 
    GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    (etc.) 
}
```

=====
Additionally, as ikerfah noted above, using pushReplacement() would have worked as well from Screen_A -> Screen_B -> Screen_C.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzX5c.png)

Issue will solve just add import material on router class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Comment: Please fix the image link description